# Should [hyperthreading] be a synonym for more general (not yet existing) [hardware-multithreading]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

While Intel x86 might be the primary focus of questions on hardware multithreading, it seems inappropriate to use a company-specific name (or rather a corruption of that name, which is actually "Hyper-Threading Technology"—note the hyphen) for what is a more general hardware technique. (Even an AMD x86 could not implement Hyper-Threading; their cross-licensing agreement with Intel applies to patents not to trademarks.)

In addition to the Intel-only nature of the name, as a brand name its meaning is less firmly fixed. Intel has used Hyper-Threading to describe the switch-on-event multithreading in Itanium implementations (introduced in the Itanium 2 9000 series). Since fewer people are familiar with Itanium this confusion is less obvious, but the confusion is unnecessary.

[hardware-multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware-multithreading) would have the additional advantage of applying to all forms of hardware multithreading (fine-grained MT, SMT, SoEMT), providing an appropriate tag for the other forms without multiplying tags. (This could be a minor disadvantage if the question is more exclusive to SMT. It would be more of a disadvantage if the question was asking specifically about Intel's use of the term, like "From a software optimization perspective, what is the difference between Xeon E7v2's and Itanium 2 9500's implementation of Hyper-Threading Technology?")

The [tag wiki for hyperthreading](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hyperthreading/info) even specifies 2-way multithreading (POWER7 cores support 4-way multithreading; SPARC M6, 8-way multithreading, Xeon Phi, 4-way multithreading, e.g.) and virtual processors (the MIPS Multithreading Application Specific Extension makes a distinction between a Virtual Processing Element and a Thread Context; a VPE can have multiple TCs).

I realize that the computer architecture perspective is different from the programming perspective, but the proposed change seems reasonable.

The main objection I can see would be when programmers are specifically referring to Intel's implementation. In that case the less specific nature of [hardware-multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware-multithreading) would be a disadvantage. This is somewhat similar to the confusion between a general concept like a hash table and a particular language/library's implementation using that name (see ["Should [tag:hashtable] and [tag:hashmap] be synonyms?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252300/2467198)).

Comment: I tagged this as a synonym-request (even though the hardware-multithreading tag does not exist) because the question seems to deal with this *type* of issue. Improvement of the tagging is encouraged.